# Как строку двоичных цифр перевести в байты, записать их в файлы и вытащить их оттуда?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю архиватор. В процессе архивирования создается строка с двоичным кодом. Мне нужно перевести эту строку в байты и записать их в файл. Потом мне нужно достать эти байты из файла и перевести их в строку обратно, без потерь данных

Перевожу в байты и записываю в файл таким образом:`

```
f = open("n.bin", "wb")

data = "1100101101"

f.write(int(data, 2).to_bytes((len(data.lstrip('0')) + 7) // 8, 'big'))`
```

Пытаюсь достать их из файла так:

```
f = open("n.bin", "rb")

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0'

print(f.read())
print(text_from_bits(f.read()))
```

Функцию text_from_bits нашел в интернете, но она не работает (как и decode()), выводит ошибку:

```
File "test_dearchive.py", line 4, in text_from_bits
    n = int(bits, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: b''
```

Как я понял, перевод в байты в первом скрипте - правильный. А как правильно взять эти байты из n.bin и перевести их в ту же строку, что была изначально в data?

Comment: 1. После первого вызова метода `read` вы уже переместились в конец файла, повторный вызов возвращает пустую последовательность байт. 2. В `bits` у вас будут байты, а не строка с двоичным представлением данных.

Comment: 1. да, действительно, f.read() меняет поведение, убрал эту функцию. 2. и как тогда лучше поступить по-другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обратный метод `from_bytes`:

```
with open('n.bin', 'rb') as f:
    print(bin(int.from_bytes(f.read(), 'big')))  # -> 0b1100101101
```